# What is a True Score Correlation?

Tags: regression

I am trying to interpret this journal article table-
[image]

It's rho is called an "estimated true score correlation" how is that different from a classic beta coefficient? And is a value of -.29 and SD of 0.21 treated in the same way that it is not significant at the 5% level?

https://psycnet.apa.org/doiLanding?doi=10.1037/0021-9010.87.4.797

Comment: https://pubpeer.com/publications/7E4DAC69149E6EB4DAE8A28AAFB030

Comment: Do these Wikipedia articles help to explain why correlation is not the same as a regression coefficient? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation